# Azure Pipelines DotNetCoreCLI - .Net Core SDK End of Life

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am receiving an error in Azure CI pipelines. While trying to run a DotNetCoreCLI `restore` task.

Been scrapping the net for hours to no avail, no solution from related questions have helped me understand the problem.

Basically, we have added a new project to a repo. This project requires a dotnet restore command to be run to create the `project.assets.json` file.

Please see script below and log snapshot for each task.

**Script:**

[image]

**UseDotNet snapshot:**

[image]

**DotNetCoreCLI error message:**

Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.

##[error]No files matched the search pattern.

Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts.

Have looked around quite a bit. Nothing seems to help me understand what is going wrong here.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the folder location referenced as `$(UtilityLibrary)`.

Took me a while to figure out as I didn't have access to the actual variable set.

Answer (score -1):

info message is caused by the fact the .NET version is out of support https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: 5.x is not out of support

Answer (score -1):

Please always check the path of the solution , proj

Comment: This question is asked more than 7 month ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer