# Azure Devops Build Keeps Failing Due to Compile Items Being Included in Project File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm running into this issue when I try to run dotnet publish in Azure Devops. It fails with the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj -o D:\a\1\a\DataIngestion -c Release
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj (in 1.65 min).
D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\Functions\SB1Parser.cs(236,36): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5097,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\local.settings.json" because it was not found. [D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish D:\a\1\s\src\S00PackageRun\S00PackageRun.csproj -o D:\a\1\a\S00PackageRun -c Release
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored D:\a\1\s\src\S00PackageRun\S00PackageRun.csproj (in 2.93 sec).
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets(190,5): error NETSDK1022: Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'Controllers\SeatPackageController.cs'; 'Core\Application\MSOffice\IExcelWriter.cs'; 'Core\Application\Storage\BlobDto.cs'; 'Core\Application\Storage\BlobResponseDto.cs'; 'Core\Application\Storage\IStorageService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Data\SqlService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Data\Startup.cs'; 'Infrastructure\MicrosoftOffice\MicrosoftExcelService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\MicrosoftOffice\MicrosoftWordService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\MicrosoftOffice\Startup.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Middleware\ErrorResult.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Middleware\Startup.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Services\DirectoryService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Services\EMCDTemplateService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Services\PackageSummaryTemplateService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Services\SB1PackageReportTemplateService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Services\Startup.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Services\TemplateServiceBase.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Startup.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Storage\BlobService.cs'; 'Infrastructure\Storage\Startup.cs'; 'Models\Application\ExcelMappingFieldAttribute.cs'; 'Models\Application\SB1PackageReportData.cs'; 'Models\Application\TSOTransmittalData.cs'; 'Models\Configurations\AppSettingsConfiguration.cs'; 'Models\Configurations\AzureConfiguration.cs'; 'Models\Configurations\ConnectionStringsConfiguration.cs'; 'Models\Configurations\Startup.cs'; 'Models\PackageCriteria.cs'; 'Models\PackageStatistics.cs'; 'Models\WordTemplateField.cs'; 'Program.cs' [D:\a\1\s\src\S00PackageRun\S00PackageRun.csproj]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [
  'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\DataIngestion\\DataIngestion.csproj',
  'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\S00PackageRun\\S00PackageRun.csproj'
]
Finishing: Dotnet publish
```

I've pasted below my project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Functions\AB3Parser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Functions\AB3Scrubber.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Functions\DropProcessor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Functions\AB1Parser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Functions\AB1Scrubber.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Functions\SB1Parser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Functions\SB1Scrubber.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\ExtensionMethods\DataTypeExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\ExtensionMethods\HttpRequestExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\ExtensionMethods\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\Services\AppInsightsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\Services\AzureBlobService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\Services\EmailService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\Services\SqlService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\DataIngestionField.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ValidRequirement.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="host.json" />
    <None Include="local.settings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Monitor.Query" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

For some reason the separate classes and functions are being included as Compile items and causing this issue. I can't delete the separate compile items because it seems to dereference them in the project file and are no longer linked. I didn't use to run into this issue before and need some guidance on this.

I am also pasting my pipeline code below, but it has worked on other project files without the compile items:
parameters:

```
  SolutionPath: ""
  TestPath: ""

stages:
- stage: Build_Test_Publish
  dependsOn: []
  pool:
    vmImage: $(poolImage)
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Test_Publish
    displayName: Restore, Test, Publish
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET global.json version'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        useGlobalJson: true
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Dotnet test
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'dotnet test -v=normal -o $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\\ -l trx -r ${{parameters.TestPath}}/TestResults ${{parameters.TestPath}}'
      condition: ne('${{parameters.TestPath}}', '')

    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish test results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
        testResultsFiles: ${{parameters.TestPath}}/**/*.trx
        searchFolder: ${{parameters.TestPath}}/TestResults
        failTaskOnFailedTests: true
      condition: ne('${{parameters.TestPath}}', '')

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Dotnet publish'
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '-o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory) -c Release'
        zipAfterPublish: true
        modifyOutputPath: true

    - task: PublishSymbols@2
      displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
      inputs:
        SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
        PublishSymbols: false
      continueOnError: true

    - publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: function'
      artifact: function
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I didn't run into this problem before, but that was because classes in the project weren't being added as compile items and conflicting with whatever the default is. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

> ```cs
> Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and
> have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these
> SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which
> are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required
> version.C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish
> D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj -o
> D:\a\1\a\DataIngestion -c Release MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
> ```

The above when occurs when you're either using Unsupported or outdated .Net Core runtime in your pipeline, As .Net 3.0 has reached EOL, It will give this warning. Second reason  as mentioned in this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736633/azure-pipelines-dotnetcorecli-net-core-sdk-end-of-life) is this warning occurs is due to the wrong path mentioned in your .Net task.

In my Pipeline **I used below path in projects** and the pipeline ran successfully, Refer below:-

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release
```

The second warning:-

> ```
> warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread[D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj]
> ```

This warning states your code with Function.cs or another class is missing await operator. Make sure you add await async method in your code.  An example of it is adding below line in your code below your namespace and public class:-

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
```

> ```
> C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5097,5):error MSB3030: Could not copy thefile"D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\local.settings.json" because it was not found [D:\a\1\s\src\DataIngestion\DataIngestion.csproj]
> ```

As the error states the local.settings.json is missing in your Function's code. During the build and deployment of Azure Functions local.settings.json is ignored in runtime as its part of gitignore, But It should be part of your local project like below:-

[image]

> ```
> error NETSDK1022: Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see
> ```

This error occurs when Duplicate items are added due to multiple projects and classes in order to resolve this error you can remove the duplicates or refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275700/fixing-the-duplicate-compile-items-were-included-error-in-visual-studio#:%7E:text=Probably%20the%20easiest%20way%20to%20fix%20this%20for,projects%20at%20once.%20%3CProject%3E%20%3CPropertyGroup%3E%20%3CEnableDefaultCompileItems%3Efalse%3C/EnableDefaultCompileItems%3E%20%3C/PropertyGroup%3E%20%3C/Project%3E) here  by jessehouwing and user10191234 is to set 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false',  and Exclude Obj folder, Refer below:-

> ```xml
> <Project>
>     <PropertyGroup>
>          <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
>     </PropertyGroup> </Project>
> ```

Your Project file with excluded compile items:-

> ```xml
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">   <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
>     <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
>     <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
>     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
>     <PackageReference Include="Azure.Monitor.Query" Version="1.1.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.13.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http"
> Version="3.0.13" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi"
> Version="1.5.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs"
> Version="5.0.1" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.9.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.1" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
>     <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
>     <None Update="host.json">
>       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
>     </None>
>     <None Update="local.settings.json">
>       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
>       <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
>     </None>   </ItemGroup> </Project>
> ```

> ```
> NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
> ```

Use the below task to resolve this compatibility issue with .Net 5

```yaml
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release
```

```yaml
  - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET global.json version'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        useGlobalJson: true
        version: 6.x
```

***My YAML pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '<subscription-id>'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc123'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/FunctionApp8'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET global.json version'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.x'



    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

**Build and Publish Task:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**After the Build and Publish Deployment of function was successful in function app**, Refer below:-

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]